# Can you use Dwarven Thrower for extra attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons, attack, ranged-attack

It's not clear to me how the extra attack feature works with this weapon.

I understand that the weapon's description states that the weapon returns to the wielder's hand after thrown, but at the same time the rules say a character can only interact with an object once per turn.

Could a level 11 fighter make a ranged attack with the weapon three times in the same turn?

Answer (score 15):

The *Dwarven Thrower* states that:

> Immediately after the attack, the weapon flies back to your hand.

It says nothing about using your action, bonus action, or even your free interaction with objects... It just happens.

Therefore, yes, a level 11 fighter could get to make three attacks with the weapon per turn.